# How to prevent Yii CGridView filter on change?

Tags: php, jquery, yii

CGridView have active filter with "change" event. So every time i type something in one filter and leave this field it will change results on list.

I want to prevent this behavior and make CGridView filters only when user hits "enter" key.

So i could type values in 3 different filters and then hit enter to show results.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).off('change.yiiGridView');
```

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't working... maby cause it should target to specific input?

Comment: It worked when i did  it with register client script!

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('gridFilter',"   
        $(function(){
            $(document).off('change.yiiGridView');
        });
    ", CClientScript::POS_READY);